# Cannot edit a javascript asset in rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.2, asset-pipeline

I am trying to change the functionality of the autocomplete-rail.js file once I've done the

```
rails generate autocomplete:uncompressed
```

to get the full jquery code

however, every change that I make (in comments or in code) doesn't seem to matter

I've saved the file, restarted rails s, deleted cache.. nothing works.

the file is currently in public/assets (where the generator puts it)

I can see from the source that `/assets/autocomplete-rails.js?body=1` is being served..

going to it does not give me jquery.. but regular javascript

what is going on?

**update**

I searched for the file and if I edit the file in

```
C:\Ruby193\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\rails3-jquery-autocomplete-1.0.6\lib\assets\javascripts
```

I can see that that is the file being served.. (I edited it and I see it being served with the edit)

this is a problem in working on different computers on the same repo since the edits to this file are kept in the gems directory and not in the app's..

is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved.. I just copied that file to the assets directory directly..

Answer (score 0):

If the file exists in `public/assets`, then that's the file that the web server will serve. I suggest you delete that entire directory so that Rails will dynamically serve your assets.